# MapPartitionFunction returning null value

Tags: java, apache-spark, data-partitioning

I am using java spark. Here, I am reading Dataset from hdfs and then applying mapPartition on that. At the end of call function, I can see output Row have value which is not getting collected in my df2 Dataset. Below is my code.

main method

```
Dataset<Row> df = readDataFrame();
        df.show();
Dataset<Row> df2 = df.mapPartitions(new DataframeProcessMap(getConfig()), RowEncoder.apply(getSchema()));
```

DataframeProcessMap class

```
public class DataframeProcessMap implements MapPartitionsFunction<Row,Row> {
    private final Config config;

    public  DataframeProcessMap(Config config){
        this.config=config;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Row> call(Iterator<Row> iterator) throws Exception{
        List<Row> outputRows = new ArrayList();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            Row inputRow = iterator.next();
            ArrayList output = projectAndRenameColumn(inputRow);
            Row outputRow = DataIntegrationUtils.getRow(output.toArray(), getSchema());
            System.out.println(outputRow);
            outputRows.add(outputRow);
        }
        return outputRows.iterator();
    }
    public ArrayList projectAndRenameColumn(Row inputData){
    ...
    // Some processing
    }
    public StructType getSchema(){
    ...
    //schema from config file
    }

}
```

getSchema() also present in main class which is exact same as this.

In call method
System.out.println(outputRow);
giving me correct output. However, I am getting null Rows in df2.why??